# intellijidea debug system of 3 projects

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle

I have 3 java 8 gradle projects, A,B,C.
A and C depends on B. A and C are not connected with each other directly.
I want to debug my changes for project B and see how project A reacts on my changes for project B. How to debug iе in intellijidea? Change B, compile jar, copy jar, test A? It`s really boring and wrong, how to do it?

UPDATE:
Those 3 projects needs to be separated, because different people working on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure your Module dependencies for A and C to directly use the source of B. This allows you to debug code in A, B and C at the same time without requiring a JAR to be build. See the screenshots below for a step by step process.

First of all, open a project and go to the Project Structure (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S). The goal is to have modules A, B and C part of your project:

[image]

You can press the `+` button at the top to `Import Module`. (Depending on whether you already have modules set up for these other projects, you might need to select `New Module` or `Gradle` instead.)

Once you have the three modules in there, you should update their dependencies so it looks like the image below. Here you can see module C having a dependency on module B. To add such a dependency, click the `+` sign to the right of the list of dependencies and select `Module Dependency`. If the JAR file for the depending module is also still in the list, remove it.

[image]

Now press OK and trigger a rebuild of your project (`Build > Rebuild Project`). If everything compiles, you can now make code changes anywhere or even debug all three modules at the same time.